# engineering.stackexchange, Appropriate Question?

Tags: discussion, questions, multiple-questions

First I want to apologize to the group for asking a question that I agree was way too broad.  With that said I thought best to come here and discuss the possibility of posting another question.

Note that in the body of the question, I want to ask a simple question and I want to differentiate that question from the research that I did into trying to answer my own question.  So I thought I will litterly be using the word 'Question' in bold and 'Background' in bold to differentiate the two.

**Is this question appropriate for the group?**

**Title:  Components of Machine for Melt Blown Fabric used in N-95 Masks**

**Question:**

What are main components of a machine for producing Melt Blown Fabric suitable for N95 masks[1]?  Which of these parts are difficult to mass produce and why?

**Background:**

Various research and citations......

Comment: Hey Roger... Sorry for the tour of metas but you need to ask this on the meta site associated with the site where you want to know whether it's on topic or not. Every site has a meta site, so if you're talking about Electrical Engineering, go to https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

To avoid your questions attracting votes and flags for them to be closed as **Needs more focus**, I think it is always best to ask only one focused question per question.

Every additional question mark in your question, unless it is part of a quote, risks someone interpreting it as multiple questions in your question.

While some sites are less insistent upon there being "only one question per question" than others, I think doing as I suggest above on most sites will mean your questions are much less likely to receive any close votes/flags for needing more focus.